# Why does Nepos use the accusative here?

Tags: classical-latin, cornelius-nepos

My son was assigned an excerpt from the *Vitae* of Nepos, [Lysander 4](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0136:life=lys.:chapter=4), and hit a snag at the end of this sentence:

> nam cum Lysander praefectus classis in bello multa crudeliter avareque fecisset deque iis rebus suspicaretur ad cives suos esse perlatum, petiit a Pharnabazo ut ad ephoros sibi testimonium daret, quanta sanctitate bellum gessisset sociosque tractasset, deque ea re accurate scriberet: **magnam enim eius auctoritatem in ea re futuram**.

One can sort of intuit that the bold part at the end means something like "for his authority would be great in this matter", and that more or less matches a  [public-domain translation](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/nepos.htm#Lysander) that I found online.

But I can't figure out, in the grammatical context, why *magnam ... auctoritatem ... futuram* is accusative. As Draconis has pointed out in the comments, this feels like an indirect statement with an implied *esse* rounding out *futuram*, but it seems like the text should include one more verb that introduces the indirect statement; something like "he thought" or the like.

Is there maybe a classical idiom in play here that I'm unaware of? (I'm more familiar with medieval Latin)

Comment: Hint: think of the _futuram_ as _futuram esse_, an infinitive.

Comment: yes it definitely feels like a Latin indirect statement but where is the 'direct' verb?

Comment: @Ben Dunlap: The use of "futuram (esse)" may give "his authority will be great". Ex. "(dicit) hostes venturos esse" = "(he says) the enemy will come".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *verbum dicendi* is missing.

This is fine, because from *petiit*, we know Lysander is talking to Pharnabazos; this is part of his petition. Allen and Greenough have [this](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0001:part=2:section=12) to say:

> The verb of saying etc. is often not expressed, but implied in some word or in the general drift of the sentence